# php button does not call function

Tags: php

I have some php code that is meant to write variables in an array to a file when clicking a button, but the code I have for the button onclick event doesnt seem to be called at all, the echo line doesnt even display at all. Everything works fine except for the button, doesnt even give any warning/error messages so I am kind of lost on what the problem is. Here is the code for reference:

```
<?php
session_start();
$arr = $_SESSION['arr'];
session_destroy();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <body>
        <h1> Selected tasks <br></h1>

        <?php 
            foreach($arr as $selected)
                echo $selected ."<br>" ."<br>";
        ?>

        <button onclick = "clicked()"> Export </button>

        <?php 
            function clicked() {
                echo "function called";
                $myfile = fopen("To Do List.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

                foreach($arr as $selected)
                    fwrite($myFile, $selected . "\n");

                fclose($myfile);
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do this with `PHP` you need `AJAX` to achieve your requirement,  call javascript or jquery function on click. call ajax and put your code in `Ajax` called URL page.

Comment: I tried to put the open/write/close all together in the foreach loop because as the code is now, it creates the file but doesn't write to it. I thought I should edit the question with my changes since it was the same code.

Answer (score 2):

PHP code runs on server-side to output HTML code for client's browser.
After the HTML code (that generated by PHP on the server) is downloaded to the client's browser, when that button is clicked, the browser calls a JavaScript function `clicked()`, not a PHP function.

Comment: How should I call/write the function then? What would be the correct way to write this in PHP?

Comment: You should write JavaScript code that works in the user's browser.
PHP just runs on the server and outputs HTML code.

Comment: If you want to create a file on the server side, rather than on the user side, by clicking a button, you can use the "submit" of input or button to send a new request to the server, and have the Perl or PHP code that receives the request do the processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$arr = $_SESSION['arr'];
session update();   
session_destroy();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <body>
        <h1> Selected tasks <br></h1>

        <?php 
            foreach($arr as $selected)
                echo $selected ."<br>" ."<br>";
        ?>

        <button onclick = "clicked()"> Export </button>

        <?php 
            function clicked() {
                echo "function called";
                $myfile = fopen("To Do List.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

                foreach($arr as $selected)
                    fwrite($myFile, $selected . "\n");

                fclose($myfile);
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function session_update()" when adding that line you recommended in the top section. Is there more to it that I am missing?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).